# Interaction Script not sending transactionSignature

Tags: typescript, transactions, web3js, solana, solana-web3js

I am writing an interaction script in Typescript using Solana's web3.js library.

The following is my code:

```
/*  What this program will do?
    Our client will ping a counter program, which will increment a counter. 
    I'm going to tell everyone on the network that I'm a builder
*/

// I'm adding these
import * as Web3 from '@solana/web3.js';
import * as fs from 'fs'; // for file handling
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

// WE NEED TO KNOW WHAT ACCOUNTS THESE INSTRUCTIONS ARE DEALING WITH, THESE ARE 2 DUMMY ACCOUNTS
const PROGRAM_ID = new Web3.PublicKey("ChT1B39WKLS8qUrkLvFDXMhEJ4F1XZzwUNHUt4AU9aVa")
const PROGRAM_DATA_PUBLIC_KEY = new Web3.PublicKey("Ah9K7dQ8EHaZqcAsgBW8w37yN2eAy3koFmUn4x3CJtod")

async function initializeKeypair(connection : Web3.Connection): Promise<Web3.Keypair> {
    if(!process.env.PRIVATE_KEY) {
        console.log("Generating secret key...️");
        const signer = Web3.Keypair.generate();

        console.log("Creating .env file...");
        fs.writeFileSync('.env', `PRIVATE_KEY=[${signer.secretKey.toString()}]`);

        return signer;
    }

    const secret = JSON.parse(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY ?? '') as number[];
    const secretKey = Uint8Array.from(secret);
    const keypairFromSecret = Web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(secretKey);
 
    // When creating it from the secret key
    await airdropSolIfNeeded(keypairFromSecret, connection);
    
    return keypairFromSecret;
}

async function airdropSolIfNeeded(signer : Web3.Keypair, connection : Web3.Connection) {
    const balance = await connection.getBalance(signer.publicKey);
    console.log('Current balance is ', balance / Web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL, 'SOL');

    //1 SOL is enough for anything we do
    if(balance / Web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL < 1) {
        // We can only get up to 2 SOL per request 
        console.log("Airdropping 1 SOL...");
        const airdropSignature = await connection.requestAirdrop(signer.publicKey, Web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL);

        const latestBlockhash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

        await connection.confirmTransaction({
            blockhash : latestBlockhash.blockhash,
            lastValidBlockHeight : latestBlockhash.lastValidBlockHeight,
            signature : airdropSignature,
        });

        const newBalance = await connection.getBalance(signer.publicKey);
        console.log('The new balance is ', newBalance / Web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL, 'SOL');
    }
}

async function pingProgram(connection : Web3.Connection, payer : Web3.Keypair) {
    const transaction = new Web3.Transaction(); // 1. WE MAKE A TRANSACTION
    const instruction = new Web3.TransactionInstruction({ // 2. WE MAKE AN INSTRUCTION
        // Instructions need 3 things 
    
        // (i) The public keys of all the accounts the instruction will read/write
        keys : [
            {
                pubkey : PROGRAM_DATA_PUBLIC_KEY,
                isSigner : false,
                isWritable : true
            }
        ],
        // (ii) The ID of the program this instruction will be sent to
        programId : PROGRAM_ID

        // (iii) Data - in this case, there's none!
    });

    transaction.add(instruction); // 3. WE ADD THIS INSTRUCTION TO THE TRANSACTION
    console.log(transaction)
    const transactionSignature = await Web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [payer]); // 4. WE SEND THE TRANSACTION TO THE NETWORK
    console.log(transactionSignature)
    console.log(`Transaction https://explore.solana.com/tx/${transactionSignature}?cluster=devnet`);
}

async function main() {
    const connection = new Web3.Connection(Web3.clusterApiUrl('devnet'));
    const signer = await initializeKeypair(connection);

    console.log('Public Key : ', signer.publicKey.toBase58()); // Solana Public keys are Base58 alphanumeric characters

    pingProgram(connection, signer);
}

main()
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Finished successfully")
        process.exit(0)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
        process.exit(1)
    })
```

The function pingProgram does not log the latest blockhash when I console log the transaction, neither does it log the transaction signature.

The output looks like this:

[image: output]

I tried writing the code to get the latest blockhash but it isn't showing in the transaction object. I was expecting to get an output with my transaction signature like `https://explore.solana.com/tx/${transactionSignature}?cluster=devnet` so that I could check my ping on the solana explorer website.

Answer (score 1):

I think u just need to add await before calling your pingProgram(connection, signer) function to main function:

async function main(){

```
await pingProgram(connection, signer);
```

}